# Selenium: Form is not visible even after Wait is applied

Tags: ajax, selenium-webdriver, ajaxform, webdriverwait

I'm practicing Selenium with MVC application that has partial view.

When the page is rendered, I see the form displayed:

```
 <form action="/MyScreen/SaveData?Length=20" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-complete="handleComplete" data-ajax-failure="CheckError" data-ajax-loading="#loader" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#partialPlaceHolder" id="TicketDetailForm" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">

    <div id="partialPlaceHolder" style="width:100%;">

       <div id="Ticket-Details"></div>

    </div>

</form>
```

This form has a button I need to click.

I'm using Wait to make sure the form is displayed before I click on the button:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); 
WebElement ticketForm = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("TicketDetailForm")));

boolean isForm = ticketForm.isDisplayed();
```

When executing the above code, I'm getting the following error:

> Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located
>   by By.id: TicketDetailForm.

I modified the code to get the elements gradually and was able to locate the form and a placeholder where the Button is rendered.

I'm using Wait to locate a content of the form:

```
List<WebElement> forms = renderBody.findElements(By.tagName("form"));
WebElement placeHolder = forms.get(0).findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='partialPlaceHolder']"));

WebElement ticketDetail = placeHolder.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='Ticket_Details']"));
```

I cannot locate ticketDetail `WebElement

What might that be?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the form partial view is displayed by checking its element list size and then click the button which you want to click when the list size > 0
For example:

```
boolean partialViewDisplayed = false;
List<WebElement> partialViewElement= driver.findElements(By.id("Ticket-Details"));
while(!partialViewDisplayed){
    if(partialViewElement.size()>0){
        //Mark the boolean partialViewDisplayed true
        partialViewDisplayed = true;
    }
}
//Perform the further operations from here
```

Comment: I was able to see the form when I used `tagName` as a locator, however, there is other content inside of the form coming from a partial view that is not rendered using `Wait`. I updated the code correspondingly

Comment: Can you share the div structure of the content that you need to check if its displayed or not. However the logic that i have used can be applied to that also, you just need to replace the xpath/id of the form with the content that you need to check if its displayed or not.

Comment: So just to confirm, you need to wait till `<div id="Ticket-Details"></div>` gets displayed ?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check now and let me know if it works

Comment: `isDisplayed` never changes to `true`

Comment: Please try the code i have answered and let me know if it works